# Displaying images in a folder automatically

Tags: image, asp-classic, directory, tabular

I have a file with over 100 images in them, I want to be able to display the images in a 4 wide table with it extending however far it goes, how do I do this in asp classic?

Comment: Your question are not specific. With kind of file you have? Is a zip file? Is a Folder? For the table you need use Ajax and JavaScript to dinamically increase the table size.

Comment: Actually, that's not true, depending upon how the files can be accessed. It's possible that the solution would be to simply iterate through the images and generate the necessary HTML on the server side alone.

But the first point is correct -- you say a "file" -- is it a zip file, or do you mean a folder with 100 image files, or what?

Comment: Extending vertically?

Comment: Show us what you've got first - we don't just write the code for you.

Comment: @pee2pee: The OP means that he wants there to be four columns across by however many rows, vertically, to fit the bill.

Comment: Also, do you genuinely mean a **file** or do you actually mean a **folder**?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the asp folder object it can return a collection of all files within a folder which you can loop through creating your table and images in HTML
http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_files.asp